# Does a subgroup need to have the same identity as the original group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the group $G = \mathrm{SO}(3)$. It is formed by real $3 \times 3$ matrices that are orthogonal, i.e., $R^\intercal R = \mathbb{1}$. Consider now the subspace $H$ of matrices with the form
$$R = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a & b \\ 0 & c & d\end{pmatrix}$$
where
$$S = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$$
is orthogonal, i.e., $S^\intercal S = \mathbb{1}$. $H$ is a group, in fact it is isomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}(2)$. Its identity is given by
$$\mathbb{1}_H = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$
which is not the identity of $G$.

Is $H$ a subgroup of $G$? If not, which sorts of results would get broken if we were to consider $H$ a subgroup?

Comment: The subgroup axioms would be "broken" - see the duplicate. But here it is easier to see: your matrix $R$ is **not** in $SO(3)$, since its determinant is zero. But orthogonal matrices have determinant $\pm 1$.

Comment: The way to fix this, is to take $1$ as the left upper entry in $R$. Then $SO(2)$ is a subgroup of $SO(3)$ by inclusion, and the neutral elements coincide.

Comment: The neutral element of a group is its unique idempotent. Thus subgroups have the same identity.